# Window with dynamic size to keep its current size after loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Window that has dynamic width and height and a user control as content.

Based on several conditions in my view model several controls of my user control are visible or not visible.

Using `SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight` nicely WPF make my window appears perfectly with the correct dimensions to fit everything that has to be visible according to my Bindings that take effect during `Loaded` event of my user control.

My problem is that I have a `TextBox` with no defined width where if the user types in too many characters it forces my Window to grow in width, and I don't want that!

Is there a way to avoid that without writing to much code and without loosing the functionality that if user resizes the window, everything in there change automatically to fit the new size?

What I want is that every control (or the window itself) will keep its current size and not to grow outside of current window's bounds.

I hope I made clear my problem and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for the MaxWidth property of the TextBox, try to bind it to the Textbox-es parent controls Width and then if you type a longer text then it shouldn't grow larger.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can't do that because the width of the TextBox is not equal to the width of its parent. It has a TextBlock before it.

Comment: And if you would bind it the controls ActualWidht?

Comment: As long as the SizeToContent of the window is set to WindowAndHeight the TextBox will continue to grow. I will post an answer later on how I partially solved it but I was looking for a more elegant answer... Thanks anyway